# Apache service keeps failing to start

Tags: apache-2.4, debian-bullseye

So, it's as the title says. Apache doesn't start no matter what I try, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong.

systemctl status apache2 reports

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-02-13 18:25:00 UTC; 5min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 73478 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 227ms

Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname apachectl[73478]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 73486 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 73509 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 73486 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 73509 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 73486 (PassengerAgent) remains running after unit stopped.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 73509 (PassengerAgent) remains running after unit stopped.
Feb 13 18:25:00 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

journal -xe reports:

```
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has begun execution.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1774.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname apachectl[75877]: AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.vhost:7
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname apachectl[75874]: Action 'start' failed.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname apachectl[75874]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 75882 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 75905 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 75882 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 75905 (PassengerAgent) with signal SIGKILL.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 75882 (PassengerAgent) remains running after unit stopped.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit process 75905 (PassengerAgent) remains running after unit stopped.
Feb 13 18:34:32 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1774 and the job result is failed.
```

/var/log/apache/error.log lists the following:

```
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5078 75882/7f66a782b700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:531 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5079 75882/7f66a8164980 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:900 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5080 75882/7f66a6fa9700 Ser/Server.h:816 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5080 75882/7f66a6fa9700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5081 75882/7f66a782b700 Ser/Server.h:816 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5081 75882/7f66a782b700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished

[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5082 75887/7f81c0c56700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:421 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5082 75887/7f81c0d48980 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:491 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5082 75887/7f81b3fff700 Ser/Server.h:816 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5083 75887/7f81b3fff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5083 75887/7f81c0c56700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5087 75882/7f66a6727700 Ser/Server.h:816 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5087 75882/7f66a6727700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2023-02-13 18:34:32.5088 75887/7f81c0d48980 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
```

When i check the configuration with apachectl configtest and apachectl -t, they both report

```
Syntax OK
```

I've tried reinstalling but still get the same result. What else can I check that could be causing this failure?
*hostname is the name of my server for anonymity sake

Comment: I have no experience with Passenger, but the issue seems to be with PassengerAgent, not Apache.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I tried disabling the module, and now it reports the same kind of error but for vlogger this time: Feb 13 20:24:20 hostname systemd[1]: apache2.service: Killing process 106112 (vlogger) with signal SIGKILL.